# Chai.request.agent does not persist cookies between requests

Tags: node.js, cookies, chai

I am encountering a strange issue when working with Chai.request.agent. Below is my test code:

```
const chai = require("chai");
const chaiHttp = require("chai-http");
chai.use(chaiHttp);
let agent;

beforeEach(() => {
  agent = chai.request.agent(app);
});

afterEach(() => {
  agent.close();
});

it("should do something", async () => {
  //Log in
  const res = await agent.post("/api/my-endpoint").send(userDetails);

  expect(res).to.have.cookie("my-cookie");

  //Test endpoint
  const res2 = await agent.get("/api/my-other-endpoint");
  expect(res2).to.have.status(200);
});
```

The second request is sent to an endpoint that checks for the presence of my-cookie, returning a 401 if it is not present and a 200 if it is. I am getting a 401 here, and I know it is triggered by the lack of my-cookie as console.logs are logged from the piece of code that handles the check.

Here is the endpoint code:

```
router.post("/my-endpoint", async function (req, res) {
try {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      { id: 4 },
      process.env.SECRET,
      { expiresIn: "12h" }
    );

    res.cookie("my-cookie", token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 12 * 1000,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "strict",
    });

    res.sendStatus(200);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "ERROR: log in failed" });
  }
});

router.get("/my-other-endpoint", async function (req, res) {
  try {
    const cookies = req.cookies;

    if (!cookies?.my-cookie) {
      console.log("No cookie"); //This gets logged
      return res.sendStatus(401);

    } else {
      res.sendStatus(204);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "ERROR" });
  }
});
```

I have tried copying the promise chaining example from the docs but when I use this approach the second request does not run

Comment: Provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added the endpoint code

Comment: There is no set cookie code in `/my-endpoint` API.

Comment: Make your code correctly. Change `cookies?.my-cookie` to `cookies?.['my-cookie']`

Comment: Makes no difference, same test failure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `secure` option to `false` or unset it.

`app.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(cookieParser());
app.post('/my-endpoint', function (req, res) {
  res
    .cookie('my-cookie', 'abc123', {
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 12 * 1000,
      // secure: true,
      sameSite: 'strict',
    })
    .sendStatus(200);
});

app.get('/my-other-endpoint', function (req, res) {
  console.log('my-cookie: ', req.cookies['my-cookie']);
  if (!req.cookies['my-cookie']) {
    console.log('No cookie');
    res.sendStatus(401);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(204);
  }
});

module.exports = app;
```

`app.test.js`:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const app = require('./app');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
const { expect } = chai;

let agent;

beforeEach(() => {
  agent = chai.request.agent(app);
});

afterEach(() => {
  agent.close();
});

it('should do something', async () => {
  const res = await agent.post('/my-endpoint').send({});
  expect(res).to.have.cookie('my-cookie');
  const res2 = await agent.get('/my-other-endpoint');
  expect(res2).to.have.status(204);
});
```

Test result:

```
my-cookie:  abc123
  ✓ should do something

  1 passing (18ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   84.61 |       50 |     100 |   84.61 |                   
 app.js   |   84.61 |       50 |     100 |   84.61 | 21-22             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```